# How to get enclosing element of a ContextMenu, using sender

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, contextmenu, sender

I have a contextmenu that's located inside a grid. In the contextmenu's closed-event I need to get hold of the encapsulating grid. I'm aware that I can, in the newest silverlight toolkit, use:

```
var cm = sender as ContextMenu;

var grid = cm.Owner as Grid;
```

However, i want to solve it with my current (older) toolkit-version.

```
private void Contextmenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // insert solution here
}
```

Does anyone know how i can achieve this?

Update: tried about everything, couldnt figure it out. Ended up installing the newest toolkit.

Comment: I wonder about this as well. Anyone?

Answer (score -1):

```
<toolkit:MenuItem Header="Add"  Click="MenuItem_Click"/>    

private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
            MessageBox.Show("You chose to  " + menuItem.Header.ToString(),"Result",MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }
```